# Cross-correlation between images

Tags: python, image-processing, fft, cross-correlation

I'd like to compute the cross correlation using de Fast Fourier Transform, for cloud motion tracking following the steps of the image below.

[image]

```
def roi_image(image):
    image = cv.imread(image, 0)
    roi = image[700:900, 1900:2100]
    return roi

def FouTransf(image):
    img_f32 = np.float32(image)
    d_ft = cv.dft(img_f32, flags = cv.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
    d_ft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(d_ft)

    rows, cols = image.shape
    opt_rows = cv.getOptimalDFTSize(rows)
    opt_cols = cv.getOptimalDFTSize(cols)
    opt_img = np.zeros((opt_rows, opt_cols))
    opt_img[:rows, :cols] = image 
    crow, ccol = opt_rows / 2 , opt_cols / 2
    mask = np.zeros((opt_rows, opt_cols, 2), np.uint8)
    mask[int(crow-50):int(crow+50), int(ccol-50):int(ccol+50)] = 1

    f_mask = d_ft_shift*mask
    return f_mask


def inv_FouTransf(image):

    f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(image)
    img_back = cv.idft(f_ishift)
    img_back = cv.magnitude(img_back[:, :, 0], img_back[:, :, 1])

    return img_back

def rms(sigma):
    rms = np.std(sigma)
    return rms

# Step 1: Import images
a = roi_image(path_a)
b = roi_image(path_b)

# Step 2: Convert the image to frequency domain
G_t0 = FouTransf(a)
G_t0_conj = G_t0.conj()
G_t1 = FouTransf(b)

# Step 3: Compute C(m, v)
C = G_t0_conj * G_t1

# Step 4: Convert the image to space domain to obtain Cov (p, q)
c_w = inv_FouTransf(C)

# Step 5: Compute Cross correlation
R_pq = c_w / (rms(a) * rms(b))
```

I'm a little confused because I've never use that technique. ¿The application es accurate?

HINT: eq (1) is : R(p,q) = Cov(p,q) / (sigma_t0 * sigma_t1). If more information is required the paper is: "An Automated Techinique or Obtaining Cloud Motion from Geostatiory Satellite Data Using Cross Correlation".

I found [this](http://devdoc.net/python/scikit-image-doc-0.13.1/auto_examples/transform/plot_register_translation.html) source but I don't know if does something I'm trying.

Comment: This is an example of the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), and yes it is correct. Not sure about OpenCV, but Scipy already implements this: [`scipy.signal.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html).

Comment: I noticed you asked several questions on Stackoverflow but forgot on all of them to click on the checkbox near the answer to select it as the official problem solver. This mechanism exists so that we help future visitors find their answers more quickly. Please take time to review all of your questions and do this: click on the checkbox near the answer that helped you solve that particular problem. By keeping up with the site's modus operandi you'll not only help keep the site organized but also increase the chances of someone else helping you again in the future.

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to do something similar to `cv2.matchTemplate()`, a working python implementation of the **Normalized Cross-Correlation** (NCC) method can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/Sabrewarrior/normxcorr2-python/blob/master/normxcorr2.py):

```
########################################################################################
# Author: Ujash Joshi, University of Toronto, 2017                                     #
# Based on Octave implementation by: Benjamin Eltzner, 2014 <b.eltzner@gmx.de>         #
# Octave/Matlab normxcorr2 implementation in python 3.5                                #
# Details:                                                                             #
# Normalized cross-correlation. Similiar results upto 3 significant digits.            #
# https://github.com/Sabrewarrior/normxcorr2-python/master/norxcorr2.py                #
# http://lordsabre.blogspot.ca/2017/09/matlab-normxcorr2-implemented-in-python.html    #
########################################################################################

import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve


def normxcorr2(template, image, mode="full"):
    """
    Input arrays should be floating point numbers.
    :param template: N-D array, of template or filter you are using for cross-correlation.
    Must be less or equal dimensions to image.
    Length of each dimension must be less than length of image.
    :param image: N-D array
    :param mode: Options, "full", "valid", "same"
    full (Default): The output of fftconvolve is the full discrete linear convolution of the inputs. 
    Output size will be image size + 1/2 template size in each dimension.
    valid: The output consists only of those elements that do not rely on the zero-padding.
    same: The output is the same size as image, centered with respect to the ‘full’ output.
    :return: N-D array of same dimensions as image. Size depends on mode parameter.
    """

    # If this happens, it is probably a mistake
    if np.ndim(template) > np.ndim(image) or \
            len([i for i in range(np.ndim(template)) if template.shape[i] > image.shape[i]]) > 0:
        print("normxcorr2: TEMPLATE larger than IMG. Arguments may be swapped.")

    template = template - np.mean(template)
    image = image - np.mean(image)

    a1 = np.ones(template.shape)
    # Faster to flip up down and left right then use fftconvolve instead of scipy's correlate
    ar = np.flipud(np.fliplr(template))
    out = fftconvolve(image, ar.conj(), mode=mode)

    image = fftconvolve(np.square(image), a1, mode=mode) - \
            np.square(fftconvolve(image, a1, mode=mode)) / (np.prod(template.shape))

    # Remove small machine precision errors after subtraction
    image[np.where(image < 0)] = 0

    template = np.sum(np.square(template))
    out = out / np.sqrt(image * template)

    # Remove any divisions by 0 or very close to 0
    out[np.where(np.logical_not(np.isfinite(out)))] = 0

    return out
```

The returned object from `normxcorr2()` is the cross correlation matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just for be sure... `out` returns (in my case) the R (p, q), right? Then I need to obtain de max[ R(p,q)] , this is with `np.max()` in order to know the maximum cross correlation coefficient, but what is exactly "p" and "q"? The coordinates of that point?

Comment: I assume `max[ R(p,q)]` represents the largest value in the array. This is what we want when looking for the best score (or correlation) in the resulting correlation matrix. Feel free to upvote the answer if it helped you or click on the checkbox near it to select it as the official problem solver.

Comment: The above implementation is the same as OpenCV "cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED"? and finally...my image and template is 200 x 200, why `out` returns a 399 x 399 array?

Comment: It's not **the same**... It's similar! If you want it to be identical to OpenCV you must change the `mode` to `'valid'`.

Comment: The correlation map its not going to be the same size as your input images. There's a little math that goes behind determining the appropriate size of the correlation map.

Comment: Alright. Is there a way to calculate the distance using this approximation?

Comment: I don't really want to extend this topic any further, I think there's more than enough to get you going. Since the function above is equivalent to `coor_map = cv2.matchTemplate(target, templ, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)`  if you adjust it to use `mode='valid'`, you can abuse OpenCV a little more to find out the best **score** and **location** of the match using: `(cv_minVal, cv_score, cv_minLoc, cv_bestLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(coor_map)`.

Comment: This what I do parallel